# Vimeo is not defined

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this errors in **console.log**.

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: Vimeo is not defined ReferenceError: Vimeo is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://unisoft.local/js/scripts.min.js:1:18238)
    at j (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js:2:29999)
    at k (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js:2:30313)

Uncaught ReferenceError: Vimeo is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (scripts.min.js:1)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
```

The code is: 
**js file:**

```
var vimeoBanner = $('#vimeo-banner');

    if (vimeoBanner[0]) {
        var vimeoPlayer = new Vimeo.Player(vimeoBanner[0]);
        vimeoPlayer.setVolume(0.2);
        vimeoPlayer.setLoop(false);
        if (firstVisit) {
            vimeoPlayer.play();
        }
    }
```

**and html:**

```
<div class="video-banner">
    <div class="video-banner__video">
        <iframe id="vimeo-banner" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/217894047?color=02b4b6" width="640" height="360"
                allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
```

Can someone help me please, I tried already to change the order of script files and it didn't work? 
Thanks.

Comment: you should include their library. the reference.

Comment: Have you include `<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>` in your html?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, you're using a reference to something that doesn't exist (i.e undefined). You probably forgot to load the library for Vimeo or misspelled it.

Comment: yes. <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script async src="//player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
<script src="../js/scripts.min.js"></script>

Comment: I have the library, it's not that.

Answer (score 2):

The variable/class is being used before it is declared. This library needs to be completely loaded first. Using the class inside a function that waits for the page to finish loading and putting the reference to the library in the header should do the trick.